# Jenkins PollScm for specific repository

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-pipeline, polling

I want to build a project using two Git repositories. One of them contains the source code, while the other has the build and deployment scripts.

I am using Jenkins pipeline for building my project. The pipeline scripts are in **Jenkins-pipeline** repository and the Source code in **middleware** repository. As my pipeline scripts are in Jenkins-pipeline repository I am configuring my pipeline with the Jenkinsfile from Jenkins-pipeline repository.

Here is the Jenkins file I am using:

```
pipeline {
agent any
parameters {
    string(name: 'repo_branch', defaultValue: 'development', description: 'The branch to be checked out')
    string(name: 'git_repo',  defaultValue: 'ssh://git@my-server.com/middleware.git' description: 'Git repository from where we are going to checkout the code')

}
options {

    buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5'))
    disableConcurrentBuilds()
    timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES')
}
triggers {
    pollSCM('* * * * *')
}
stages {
    stage('Checkout git repo') {
        steps {
            git branch: "${params.repo_branch}", url: "${params.git_repo}", credentialsId: 'git-credentials'
        }
    }
    stage('Build binary') {
        steps {
            sh "./gradlew clean build -x test"
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now, as we can see, the repository I am cloning in the Jenkinsfile is different and the repository where I am keeping my jenkinsfile is different.

**Now the issue here is:**
In Jenkins file, I am using **pollScm to trigger** my Jenkins job whenever there is a new commit in the repository but I have two repositories that I have configured for the job so

1. Source Code Repository (middleware.git)
2. Pipeline Script Repository (Jenkins-pipeline.git)

So whenever there is a commit in either of these repositories my Jenkins job is getting triggered, which I don't want! **I want to trigger My Jenkins build only when there is new commit in my Source code repository and should NOT trigger the build when there is commit in Jenkins-pipeline repositories.** How do I do that?

#### Update

I am using shared libraries in the Jenkinsfile and these libraries are also in another repository. When I am committing something in shared library repository then also Jenkins jobs are getting triggered and I am using a shared library in multiple jobs so because of that all the jobs are getting triggered which I don't want.

P.S. I can't use the webhooks to trigger my Jenkins build because of my Jenkins is in private network!

Comment: hi @kalpesh-chaudhari where you able to implement this functionality? Im actually looking at the same situation but using Jenkins with OpenShift.

Comment: @bencampbell_14 I am not able to implement this functionality yet. Do you have the issue in a shared library as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the library not to be included in the change-check, uncheck the 'Include @Library changes in job recent changes' checkbox in the 'system configuration' page for the relevant library, or set the new possible argument 'changelog=false' in the Pipeline '@Library' directive.

For the Pipeline itself to not be included in the 'pull scm' it is a bit more tricky.
One option is to include the Jenkinsfile in the code-repository, but if the Jenkinsfile itself will be changed, a build will be triggered as well, and it is not really needed.

Another option is to include, in the start of the Pipeline a check whether the change triggering the job is in the source-repository or in the pipeline-repository, and if it wasn't in the source-repository stop the build.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response! I tried the option you suggested of unchecking the 'Include @Library changes in job recent changes' checkbox in the 'system configuration'  page but still, it is triggering my Jenkins job on changes in shared libraries.

Comment: For that, you can disable the 'Include @Library changes in job recent changes' flag in the Library settings in 'Manage Jenkins'/'Configure System'

Answer (score 2):

The answer is quite easy. A [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/) always belongs in the root directory of the source code repository. You have to check in your Jenkinsfile into the middleware repository.

> Pipeline supports two syntaxes, Declarative (introduced in Pipeline 2.5) and Scripted Pipeline. Both of which support building continuous delivery pipelines. Both may be used to define a Pipeline in either the web UI or with a Jenkinsfile, though it’s generally considered a best practice to create a Jenkinsfile and check the file into the source control repository

**Update** - **Skip shared-lib trigger**

Such option to disable the changelog exists since version 2.9 of the Pipeline Shared Groovy Libraries Plugin:

```
@Library(value="mylib", changelog=false)
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to keep Jenkinfile and Source code in the separate repository and also the same thing is happing with Jenkins shared libraries (Please check the updated question). In that case I can not keep my shared library scripts in each repository and if I do that then why are we calling it shared libraries, right?

Answer (score 0):

Had similar question (not the library part), but in my case all 3 repos were declared in a Jenkinsfile and I wanted to poll just 1. Maybe if add the pipelines repo to SCM list like in snippet below, it can also be excluded from polling?
Here what worked for me, note 'poll' and 'changelog' directives:

```
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout changelog: true, poll: true, scm: scmGit(
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@my-server.com/middleware.git']]
                )
                checkout changelog: false, poll: false, scm: scmGit(
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'ssh://git@my-server.com/pipelines.git']]
                )
            }
        }
```

After one build, jenkins applies the poll directive and only starts polling middleware.git repository.